# Can Altium do via stitch patterns when interactive routing a group?

Tags: layout, altium, bus, via

I am currently only able to route a group to the next layer with a line of via's like below: [image: Vias in a row]

I would like to be able to route them something like this:
[image: Staggared Vias]

It would really save space but it takes a long time to do manually. Googling around doesn't give me much except [this](http://wiki.altium.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37585069)

> Via patterns decided by the tool can be toggled between perpendicular to the route or staggered. They can also be toggled interactively.

showing that Altium should be able to do this but I just can't find where you can toggle between various via patterns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I spent a solid hour or so trying to find the answer, gave up and asked here. Then a few minutes later I had the idea of seeing what shortcuts are available during routing (Ctrl-F1) and then finding that the 5 key will go through via patterns, one of which is the pattern I was looking for.

So, pressing 5 while routing multiple net's will give you other via patterns.

[image: Altium's generated via pattern]

Comment: I had that happen to me too where I spent a long time trying to figure something out within Altium, I ask here and then a short while later I figure it out.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer (it may take a little while before you can).

Comment: @ConnorWolf twenty hours left till it let's me. :P